# how can I turn off debug bar in Laravel on production

Tags: laravel

I installed Laravel "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar" for debug and after uploaded on live server i turn off debugger but now the logs is still appear to pages .

```
APP_DEBUG=false
```

Comment: Add `DEBUGBAR_ENABLED=false` to your `.env`

Comment: Is your `APP_ENV` set to `production`. Debugbar should not install in PROD environments (`composer require barryvdh/laravel-debugbar --dev`)

Comment: yes I was aware of that and am supprised how is that possible to show debug while i redirect specific in --dev

Comment: @kampit let me do that, thank you

Comment: Check if you accidentally uploaded a cached configuration that was made in a dev environment. If APP_DEBUG=false then it should normally not appear

Comment: and how did you 'upload' your site onto the live server?

Answer (score 0):

Don't install the dev dependencies when you deploy your application in production, that means you should add the `--no-dev` option to your composer command:

```
composer i --no-dev
```